# addClass, removeClass, if hasClass issue

Tags: jquery

I have 3 sets of buttons that behave like radio buttons.

The radio buttons work fine but I need to remove the active class for the button with an ID of #filter1-none ONLY if any of the other buttons have an active class. Would the best way be an if/then solution or can I do this with .filter?

This is the radio behavior.

```
$('.filter .btn').click(function () {
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings('.active').removeClass('active');
});
```

This is the html:

```
<div class="btn-group pull-right filter" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-large btn-flat" id="filter1-none">Show All</button>
</div>

<div class="btn-group pull-right mr filter" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-large btn-flat" id="filter1-LI">LI</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-large btn-flat" id="filter1-LPO">LPO</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-large btn-flat" id="filter1-NLI">NLI</button>
</div>

<div class="btn-group pull-right mr filter" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-large btn-flat" id="filter1-Low">Low</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-large btn-flat" id="filter1-Medium">Medium</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-large btn-flat" id="filter1-Urgent">Urgent</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  $('.filter .btn').click(function () {
        $('#filter1-none').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active').siblings('.active').removeClass('active');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand correctly, but to know if there is any other element with an 'active' class, why don't you just check if the array returned by the selector has any elements?

```
if ($('.active').length > 1) {
    // There are two elements with the 'active'
    // class. One of them is the button with id
    // filter1-none
    $('#filter1-none').removeClass('active');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, this is what you'll want for your javascript. If the button you clicked is not `#filter1-none` remove the active class from it

```
var $none = $('#filter1-none');
$('.filter .btn').click(function () {
   $none.removeClass('active');
   $(this).addClass('active').siblings('.active').removeClass('active');
});​
```